# nouveau driver and mirror monitor on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using [nouveau drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_%28software%29) in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with a Nvidia GTX560 video card connected to two monitors.

If I try to go in `Settings > displays > mirror display`, my resolution goes from 1920x1080 to 480x680 for both monitors. To avoid this I am forced to use the displays as two separate monitors, in which case the resolution stays untouched (1680x1050 the first monitor and 1920x1080 the second).

How can I configure the drivers/system to get the maximum resolution when in mirror mode?

My Config is:

> OpenGL: nouseau; 
>   Render: Gallium 0.4 on NVCE;
>   OpenGL Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.1;
>   Client glx: 1.4;
>   Server glx: SGI;
>   Server glx version: 1.4;
>   GLX version: 1.4

Comment: @Alex perhaps you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install nvidia-settings`

It's a GUI for NVIDIA users to mess with X settings, such as using multiple displays setups. Worked for me when I had to do it.

Comment: I can't use Nvidia drivers. Whenever i try to install them  (from the 304 to the 337, either from Nvidia's website or using Addition Drivers) the computer shuts down and I cannot boot from it (the only way to procedd then is to unplug the machine and re-install from Live CD).   I tried to upgrade to 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04 but the problem remains. I even tried to install Win 8 but I get the same issue.  I thik that if this was a hardware issue it shouldn't work with the nouveau drivers either, however i can only get my machine to work if I use the nouveau drivers.

Comment: `nvidia-settings` is not a driver, it's just a settings editor. Does it ask you to install any drivers when you try to install it?

Comment: I do get "additional drivers" to pop up, and I have tried all of the available options. But after (re)installing Ubuntu about 13 times, and Win_8 3 times I feel totally defeated. I can't assume it's a hardware problem because the video card/ display works with noveau drivers, but how can the system stop working when installing two completely OS (Linux and Win) if they are using proprieatry drivers?    P.S. This started last week, until then I was working with Nvidia drivers 331 perfectly!

Comment: does anybody know what to do?